# Why does my code delete an item but not fadeOut or hide when using AJAX + Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working on a to-do list that deletes tasks using Ajax. I can delete the item and refresh the page, leading to a deleted item flash. However, I want the delete to be instantaneous without a refresh of the page, i.e. using Ajax. There are no error messages unfortunately, and believe its a logic error:

Items Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:name))
    @item.user_id = @user.id
     if @item.save
       flash[:notice] = "Item was saved."
       redirect_to [@user, @item]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the item. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end

   def show
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   end

   def destroy
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])

     if @item.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "Item was removed."
     else
       flash[:error] = "Item couldn't be deleted. Try again."
     end

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
     end
  end
end
```

destroy.js.erb

```
<% if @item.destroyed? %>
   $('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>).hide("slow");
<% else %>
   $('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'><%= flash[:error] %></div>");
<% end %>
```

Item Partial

```
<% @item.each do |item| %>
  <%= link_to "", [item.user, item], method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %>
  <%= item.name %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

Routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
      resources :users do
        resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :show, :destroy]
      end

  get 'welcome/index'
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: Does the page do nothing - appearance wise - when you click the link?

Comment: Yes the page does nothing, but when I refresh it the comment is deleted and a flash notice comes up

Comment: Is there any javascript error message in the console in the browser?

Comment: Nope there is no error is the console or the terminal

Comment: Try putting format.js above format.html in respond_to

Comment: What about removing format.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to include the css id in the item partial to have it disappear on delete. A cleaner way to write it:

```
<%= content_tag :li, id: "item-#{item.id}" do %>
    <%= link_to "", [item.user, item], method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %>
    <%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

You also need to add the unordered list to the view for the page. Alternatively you could do paragraphs or divs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue before and below is my solution:

Try to add below line in your item partial:

```
<li id='#item-' +<%= @item.id %>">
  <% @item.each do |item| %>
  <%= link_to "", [item.user, item], method: :delete, remote: true, class:    'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %>
  <%= item.name %>
  <br>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

From your code, I don't see any CSS class for $('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>, so I guess this is the part you missed.

Let me know if it works.